# How to convert the paypal adaptive payment SDK from C# to VB in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

The Adaptive Payment SDK files are written in C# .NET.
Has anybody on here tried to convert Adaptive Payment SDK from C# to VB.NET and succeeded ?
I have contacted PayPal through their technical support and did not receive an answer.

Comment: woah wassup with caps lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could see, the CS files are two with less than 3000 lines, and the sdk itself is a dll file.

You could convert said files with: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/
and then import the sdk library to a vb project. or better yet, learn to use C#.

Comment: I am confused with the list of sample files that come with it. do   you integrate them or just the sdk file itself in which case their are numerous files to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you convert them, can't you just use the precompiled libraries?
Anyway, you can use VB and C# in different projects in the same solution.

Comment: what about the sample files named Pay.aspx.designer.cs and the rest do they not require conversion too

Comment: if you can live with the limitations implied by different language projects on one solutions, then they do not require conversion. For example when you ctrl+click a function from an imported library, VS won't take you to the definition of the function in your other project(the SDK). Actually, that's the beauty and the whole point of .NET, you can use libraries written in a different language because all .NET projects are translated to CLR. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime)